# To what extent can Jakobson's communicative functions be applied to an analysis of written texts?

Tags: terminology, text-classification

As a tutor of teachers in Spain taking the state entrance exam for English I am often confronted with the typical exam question 'identify the communciative fuctions' for text analysis. The teachers are encouraged to reference a source, and the most common choice is Jakobson. However, as I understand it, and fully recognizing my limited knowedge of linguistics, these are based on spoken, rather than written communication and although I consider some aspects are applicable - the referential function, for example, other are potentially confusing. How does the phatic function appear in writing for example, given that deixis often operates differently in speech than written word? What is 'phatic' when the writer cannot be sure who their audience is? And how do text-types influence what could be seen an functions but are actually elements of rhetorical or literary convention? I have spent many hours debating these isues with students and colleagues but as yet have failed to reach a conclusion.